# Add an Exception to a Route with Params

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I have these two routes

```
get     '/opportunities/:id(/:tab_name)'  => 'opportunities#show',     as: 'opportunity'
get     '/opportunities/:id/edit'         => 'opportunities#edit',     as: 'edit_opportunity'
```

But of course the `edit` route doesn't it work because it's received as a param for `:tab_name`. How can I make `edit` an exception?

Thanks.

Comment: I did put the `edit` route above the first one and the edit route works but I'm sure there's a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the edit route above the other route is the only way to fix this. Routes are matched in a top-down fashion.

Comment: But isn't there a way of doing conditions to a route?